# UITableView section to be sorted with one property and display another for the title

Tags: uitableview, ios4, ios5

I have a core data UITableView, the core data managed object has 4 properties (headerTitle, headerNumber, objectTitle, objectComment).

I want the UITableView sectioned by headerNumber but have the titleForHeaderInSection be the headerTitle property. Currently I have this code below....

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[__fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [sectionInfo name]];
}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (__fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return __fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"headerNumber" cacheName:@"Master"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
         // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
         // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return __fetchedResultsController;
}
```

the headerNumber is the numerical year and month like 201206 for June of 2012.
the headerTitle is the words of the headerNumber, for instance "June 2012"

does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this following method for showing headerTitle property in table view

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

NSString *sectionTitle = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];

//return a view with uiLable and show your headerTitle there

}
```

and use following method for showing headerNumber property

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
      // put your code here 
}
```

Hopw this will help you

Comment: thanks...this does help. I haven't gotten it to work yet but I think Im heading in the right direction now.